# Fourier Transform log(1 + x^2)

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

How can I prove that the Fourier transform of $\log(1 + x^2)$ is given by $-\frac{\sqrt{2\xi} e^{-|\xi|}}{|\xi|}$? (I am using $\xi$ as my Fourier variable.)

Answer (score 1):

You have  for some constant $c$ that the Fourier Transform (w.r.t. $x$) of $f(c,x) = 1/(x^2 + c)$ is given by $F(c,\xi) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 c}} \exp(-\sqrt c|\xi|)$.

[You can find this result e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier-Transformation) in the table "Quadratisch integrierbare Funktionen" where you set $c = a^2$.]

Now regarding $c$ as a variable and integrating w.r.t. $c$ gives $g(c,x) = \int f(c,x) \rm{d} c = \log (x^2 + c)$. Hence the Fourier Transform of $g(c,x)$ is (apart from some possible constant) 
$$G(c,x) = \int F(c,x) {\rm{d}} c   = \int \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2 c}} \exp(-\sqrt c|\xi|) {\rm{d}} c  \quad .$$

Substituting $c= b^2$ gives ${\rm{d}} c = 2 b \, {\rm{d}} b $ and

$$G(b,x) =  \int \sqrt{2 {\pi}} \exp(- b |\xi|) \rm{d} b  = - \sqrt{2 {\pi}} \frac{1}{|\xi|} \exp(- b |\xi|)\quad .$$

Now setting $c=1$ (which corresponds to $b=1$) gives  $g(1,x) = \log (x^2 + 1)$ which is your function. Hence the Fourier Transform of that function is 
$G(1,x) =  - \sqrt{2 {\pi}} \frac{1}{|\xi|} \exp(-  |\xi|)\;$.  So the result that you claim in your question is not quite right: possibly just a typo where you set \xi instead of \pi .